# Force depth test against a specific depth value, instead of fragment's actual depth

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3, depth-testing

I want to draw some primitives behind everything that wrote to the depth buffer by using `glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL)` and writing to every pixel that has a depth of `1.0` (the highest and default value)

However, for this to work I have to ignore the calculated Z-depth on my primitives, forcing them to test as if it were `1.0` for all of them.

What would be the easiest way to force all fragments in a specific draw to test as having a z-depth of `1.0` regardless of the actual z-depth calculated in the vertex shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that all fragments have a depth of 1.0, the you've to ensure, that the z component of the normalized device coordinate is 1.0.
The normalized device coordinate is calculated by a [perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide) form the clip coordinate (think about that as `gl_Position.xyz / gl_Position.w`).

Set `gl_Position.z` equal `gl_Position.w`, after the clip coordinate is set, that causes that `gl_Position.z / gl_Position.w` is 1.0:

```c
gl_Position.z = gl_Position.w;
```

But note, the depth of a fragment can also be set in the fragment shader, by assigning a value to [`gl_FragDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml):
(Of course this prevents that the [Early Fragment Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test) can take place)

```c
gl_FragDepth = 1.0;
```